# Should emails sent to a PERSONAL email address field display in account's activity feed?

Tags: email, einstein

With the standard einstein activity capture, emails sent to contacts automatically get logged on the applicable account. I'm wondering if emails should be logged that were sent to the *personal* email address field for a contact, on the applicable account record?

Answer (score 0):

Activity roll-up to an associated Account (`AccountId`) is handled via a system process [based on the `WhoId` and `WhatId`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194177&language=en_US). The associated Contact would be the `WhoId` in this scenario.

The roll-up to the Account is agnostic to *why* the Task was associated to any given Account. It only takes into account, pun intended, the `WhoId` (Contact or Lead) and `WhatId` (other associated object) to which the Task is linked. Unless you [alter this roll-up behavior globally](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizeactivities_activities_account_rollup.htm&type=5), you can only change this roll-up behavior by controlling the `WhatId`, and doing so will only alter the Account association if the `WhatId` is an object associated to a different Account than the `WhoId`.

The NPSP's separate Personal Email and Work Email fields are irrelevant to the Activity roll-up mechanisms.